# Link inside Owl Carousel data-dot attribute

Tags: jquery, anchor, owl-carousel-2

When I add a link(a tag) inside data-dot attribute it breaks the layout. 
For example,

```
data-dot="<div class='meta-content'><img src='https://imagelink.com'><h4>Name</h4><a href="https://link.com" target='_blank'>Web Address</a></div>"
```

Comment: I found the problem is with the 'target' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To store HTML in an inline `data` attribute you need to HTML-encode the content so that it doesn't interfere with the outer HTML structure:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#output').append($(this).data('dot'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-dot="&lt;div class='meta-content'&gt;&lt;img src='https://imagelink.com'&gt;&lt;h4&gt;Name&lt;/h4&gt;&lt;a href='https://link.com' target='_blank'&gt;Web Address&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;">Click me</a>

<div id="output"></div>
```

That being said, it's not a good pattern to store HTML in a `data` attribute. I'd suggest storing a serialised data structure in there instead and using that to build HTML which you `clone()` from the DOM.